# Strange behaviour with transitions in Safari

Tags: html, css

If I use the below code in Chrome it runs as expected. In Safari (v13.1.1) it transitions the width and y-translate first, then the x-translate jumps into position. I'm expecting a smooth transition of all 3 properties as it does in Chrome.

```js
button = document.querySelector('.button')
block = document.querySelector('.block')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  block.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.active {
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -40px);
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Click me</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot give you an explanation as to why Safari behaves this way (although I can imagine that since the `translateX` value is in `%` — based on the `width` — it gets thrown off and waits for the latter to be in its final state before animating the former), I can offer a fix with a few tweaks (tested on Safari, Chrome and Firefox on macOS 10.15).

By removing the `width` property completely and instead animating the `left` and `right` properties (and only using `translateY`), you can achieve the same result.

Your initial state was a block centered which took up `50%` of the width; here we let the width be dictated by the `left` and `right` of `25%` each, leaving the remaining `50%` for the width.

The `transform` has been simplified to just affect `translateY` — the `top` values remains unchanged.

In your active state, we increase the `left` and `right` values to `30%` each, totaling `60%` and leaving us with `40%` for the width, same as before.

```js
button = document.querySelector('.button')
block = document.querySelector('.block')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  block.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.active {
  top: 100%;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Click me</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

I hope this helps, and feel free to ask if you need more clarification!

Might be worth looking into the Webkit bug tracker to see if this has been reported.

Comment: @aprilone By the way, I know this is probably a reduced test case, but please make sure to use an actual `<button>` for your… well, button!

Comment: Excellent answer. I'll look into the Webkit bug tracker.

Yes, I thought about that after I had posted, but as you say it's a reduced test case, it's done in a different way in the actual project and doesn't impact the actual problem.